# php-mysql : Making drop down list work

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to display some data from my database with a drop down menu. The data (a picture, a link,  a title, a number) will be displayed each into a small div.

I eliminated duplicated data and I made the drop down list. Also the drop down list has the values that I want. But my code doesn t seem to work. I quess the problem is that I cannot connect the "echo" of my data with my rest code so I can make my code work.

Here is my code:

```
$query="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products GROUP BY category";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<select name=\"category\">";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<option value='" . $row['category'] . "'>" . $row['category'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>" . "</br>";
```

And here is the rest of my code:

```
mysql_select_db("myapp",$con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = " . $row['category'], $con);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $mycategory = $row['category'];
  $myimage = '<img src="'.$row['image'].'" />';
  echo  "<div id='appear'>" . $myimage . '<br />' . $row['title'] . "<br  />"  
    . "<p style='color:red;' >" . "price: " . $row['price'] . "€" . "</p>"
    . '<a   href="image.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'
    . "details" . "<a>" . "</div>" ;  
}

mysql_close($con);
```

Assume that the database is connected. Also I have to use only php and mysql.

Comment: You're missing a quote before <a   href="image.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'
Accidental in your source or just on the copy and paste? Looks like all your quotes are off after that.

Comment: it was a mistake when I was trying to highlight my code!!! ^_^ thanks for the observation :) will edit now!

Comment: He clearly stated he has to use them for a class project.

Comment: @Jared ah yea I ripped that part out and tagged it homework while editing, probably should have left it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to let the user choose the category on the first page and then show him all data fitting to his choice. If you want to show the data live in the same page, as the user selects a new category, everything gets a bit more complicated.

But lets stick to the easy version. What you code does not provide till now is a navigation that calls the next php transfers the category-id. You will need to frame the first php code in a html-form element, which contains the second php file as action target. For example:

```
<form action='part2.php' method='POST'>
<?php
  /* ... your first code snippet */
?>
<input type='submit' value='Display category' />
</form>
```

When the user clicks on the 'Display category' button, your second script will be called and you can access the choosen category string over the global var $_POST['category'].

But be careful! Don't simply send data you receive per $_POST or $_GET to your database in real scenarios, it can be simply manipulated by potential attackers. Google Cross-Site-Scripting, if you are interested in the topic, but as this is a school project, i doubt that it is of any importance to you, just don't host it online afterwards!

But back to your problem. Your second code should work after you simply replace

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category=".$row['category']."",$con);
```

with

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category=".$_POST['category']."",$con);
```

And in your second posted code snipped there is a minor bug in your echo-statement, easy to track thanks to the stackoverflow code highlighting: You are missing a simple quote sign (') right in front of your opening -tag, and your closing -tag is missing the backslash (should be , as you surely know). If thats wrong in your original code and not just a copy-paste-error, php should mention this anyway!

Hope it helps, good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

<

```
?php
 $query="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products GROUP BY category";
 $result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<select name=\"category\" onchange=\"form.submit()\">";


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['category'] . "'>" . $row['category'] 
 ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>" . "</br>";
?>
```

it will help you to change the content as the value of drop down list is changed.

and for the div use the below code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['category']) && !empty($_POST['category']))
{
//rest of your div codes lie here
}
?>
```

Comment: That seems very logical. But I see the onchange event and I think this is javascript, and this put me in thoughts. I will search that on google, i didn t know that event handling has to do with php too! thanks!

Comment: thanks for the help Bikas Das but this confuses me because I have to use Ajax to call a php function with the onchange event....